# Why pip installing qpth fails with "'install_requires' must be a string" error?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm failing to install `qpth` package with pip inside of my virtual environment. It produces the following error and I fail to understand why. Would appreciate someone explaining what's the problem or how can I investigate it.

```
(venv) PS C:\Dev\python\my_test> pip install qpth
Collecting qpth
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      error in qpth setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          numpy>=1<2
               ~~~^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

This is my setup (upgraded pip and setuptools just in case):

```
OS Windows, Python 3.11.1
pip in c:\dev\python\my_test\venv\lib\site-packages (23.1.2)
setuptools in c:\dev\python\my_test\venv\lib\site-packages (67.7.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

go https://pypi.org/project/qpth/#files download `qpth-0.0.15.tar.gz`
unzip and open `setup.py`
change

```
install_requires=[
        'numpy>=1<2',
    ]
```

to

```
install_requires=[
        'numpy>=1',
    ]
```

save `setup.py` and `cd` to unzip directory
terminal run

```
pip install .
```